# How to send a request to a Heroku app through another webpage?

Tags: javascript, heroku, deployment, fetch, postman

I have a herokuapp deployed on heroku and it can pass all of my postman test. However, when I try to send a request to the herokuapp link through fetch using another project's button, it always fail and break the herokuapp. I'm trying to use the herokuapp as a server and it is already connected with my mongo database. 
I copy pasted the code from var myHeaders straight from postman's code generating function.
Here is the code for my request, I have a username and a password input on the page and this function is designed for the sign in button:

```
function signin() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
    urlencoded.append("username", "dandan");
    urlencoded.append("password", "123");

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: urlencoded,
      redirect: 'follow'
      ***mode: 'no-cors'***// This will make it work, but I don't know why
    };

    fetch("https://emma-game-server.herokuapp.com/signin", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

**[UPDATED]** I figured out adding mode:'no-cors' will give me the response, but as a noob I don't totally understand.

**[UPDATED AGAIN]** I figured out that I don't need 'no-cors' and I need to change the request form, here's the final alteration that worked:

```
function signin() {
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var raw = JSON.stringify({"username":username,"password":password});

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: myHeaders,
            body: raw,
            redirect: 'follow'
        };

        fetch("https://emma-game-server.herokuapp.com/signin", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
                if (result.success){
                    alert("Signed in as " + result.username);
                    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML=username;
                }
                else{
                    alert(result.message);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    }
```

Comment: If it is breaking the herokuapp, the issue might be on the server side.

Comment: Then how can I know what's wrong with the server? It was tested fine with postman requests, it is just my webpage call to the server that breaks the herokuapp

Comment: There is a View Logs option in Herokuapp which is the console for the herokuapp. All console messages, warnings and errors are printed there.